# String Encoding Methods: Base 43 -> Base 95

Tags: string, encoding

I'm looking for a fast way to change base 43 strings (i.e. ASCII 32-126 excluding alphabet) to base 95 (ASCII 32-126). These strings are normally 3-20 characters long - does anybody have any pseudocode for this?

Comment: Somebody, please answer.

Comment: Could you atleast mention, which programming language you are talking about?

Comment: Well, I'm actually using Scratch, which is a 'toy language' - I program advanced stuff in it for fun. Its arithmetic isn't very good. (check out Scratch here: https://scratch.mit.edu)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any other way than to first decode base-43 string to 'big integer' and then encode that as base-95 string.

For a string of 20 characters, this intermediate integer will be about log(43)/log(2)*20 = 109 bits long.

If you have access to big integer math, this conversion will be easy to implement. If you can stay under 128 bits (23 characters in base-43) then calculations can be quite fast.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have access to big integer maths. I was looking for a way to do it without converting to an integer, because that probably just takes time. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: There is Big Integer module for Scratch, but it seems to be quite slow: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/93580772/ The problem with this conversion is that bases 43 and 95 are so different that I don't think there are any shortcuts you can use to avoid Big Integer math (like you could with e.g. base 32 to base 64).